# Resolving Autofac enumerable dependencies without contravariance

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

My application has two command classes `FooCommand` and `BarCommand`, where `BarCommand` is a subclass of `FooCommand`.

```
class FooCommand
class BarCommand : FooCommand
```

I then have classes to execute these commands.

```
class FooCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<FooCommand>
class BarCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<BarCommand>
```

These command handlers are registered with Autofac as `ICommandHandler<>` services.

```
builder.RegisterType<FooCommandHandler>.As<ICommandHandler<FooCommand>>();
builder.RegisterType<BarCommandHandler>.As<ICommandHandler<BarCommand>>();
```

Then when I need to execute a command, I resolve the registered handlers using Autofac's [enumeration relationship type](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#enumeration-ienumerable-b-ilist-b-icollection-b), which works fine.

```
var barCommandHandlers = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<FooCommand>>>()
// returns [ FooCommandHandler ]
```

So far, so good. But when I resolve registered handlers for `BarCommand`, Autofac matches both the `BarCommandHandler` and `FooCommandHandler` implementations because `BarCommand` derives from `FooCommand`.

```
var barCommandHandlers = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<BarCommand>>>()
// returns [ BarCommandHandler, FooCommandHandler ]
```

This behaviour isn't too unexpected, but it's not quite what I want.

Is there a way to resolve `IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<BarCommand>>` to only provide handlers that directly implement the `ICommandHandler<BarCommand>` interface, without also including those that implement `ICommandHandler<Base>`?

Comment: instead of class command could you use interface command ? ie `IFooCommand` and `IBarCommand` without inheritance

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment: I can't duplicate the behavior. Here are some types and a unit test:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<T> where T : FooCommand { }
public class FooCommand { }
public class BarCommand : FooCommand { }
class FooCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<FooCommand> { }
class BarCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<BarCommand> { }
class BarCommandHandler2 : ICommandHandler<BarCommand> { }

[TestClass]
public class AutofacTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ContainerResolvesExpectedDependency()
    {
        var container = GetContainer();
        var barCommandHandlers = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<BarCommand>>>()
            .ToArray();
        Assert.AreEqual(2, barCommandHandlers.Length);
        Assert.IsTrue(barCommandHandlers.Any(bch => bch is BarCommandHandler));
        Assert.IsTrue(barCommandHandlers.Any(bch => bch is BarCommandHandler2));
        Assert.IsFalse(barCommandHandlers.Any(bch => bch is FooCommandHandler));
    }

    private IContainer GetContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<FooCommandHandler>().As<ICommandHandler<FooCommand>>();
        builder.RegisterType<BarCommandHandler>().As<ICommandHandler<BarCommand>>();
        builder.RegisterType<BarCommandHandler2>().As<ICommandHandler<BarCommand>>();
        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

I'm registering the various implementations of `ICommandHandler<T>`. I included an extra one - `BarCommandHandler2` - so I could verify that I'm getting a collection of multiple implementations from the container.

The tests pass. I'm registering all three types, but when I resolve `IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<BarCommand>>` I only get the two implementations that I expect.

That makes sense because `FooCommandHandler` doesn't implement `ICommandHandler<BarCommand>`. If the container did resolve that then it would be a bug.

My recommendation would be to look over the part where you're resolving `IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<BarCommand>>`. Perhaps you've got some additional generics at work, and at runtime you're actually resolving something else.

Comment: Also, if you compare the container registration in the OP to what's in my answer, it's not quite the same. `builder.Register<FooCommandHandler>.As<ICommandHandler<FooCommand>>();` doesn't compile.

Comment: Thanks Scott, this is really useful, it's good to know this works all as expected. You're exactly right in that there might be additional generics at work, the actual code is a bit more complex and uses reflection to build the generic types, the code posted is a simplification, so it might be something to do with that. I'll continue to investigate.